# Partitioning Data by Year and Month based on long based date column using Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, date-format, partition

I have the following dataframe

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- school: string(nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string(nullable = true)
 |-- created_date: long(nullable = false)
```

I want to store the data in this dataframe partioned by year and months based on the created_date column.

```
newDataframe=originaldataframe.select(col("id"),col("name"),col("school"),col("subject"),date_format(from_unixtime(col["created_date"]/1000,"MM-dd-yyyy"),"MM-dd-yyyy")).cast('date')
    dataframePationed= newDataframe.withColumn("year", year(newDataframe.created_date)).withColumn("month", month(newDataframe.created_date)).drop("created_date")
    dataframePationed.write.partitionBy("year", "month").format("csv").save("path/to/partion/data")
```

But after long data type is converted date format if I try to print createdDate column value is shown as null. How can I achieve this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If we change date format to any format other than spark's default format("yyyy-MM-dd") and use cast method on converted column then you will get null.

You can try any oneof below code:

```
to_date(from_unixtime(col["created_date"]/1000))
date_format(from_unixtime(col["created_date"]/1000),'MM-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: Even after I changing based on your answer still the values are null

Comment: Edited the answer, check with that.

Comment: month()  and year() function will give proper values if the date format is yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: date_format(from_unixtime(col["created_date"]/1000),'yyyy-MM-dd'). Only this worked. Thanks